# TypeError: Object of type 'AdgroupPlacementSpecificReviewFeedback' is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Unable to parse the following as json. This is what is returned from graph api, under the ad_review_feedback field. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup-review-feedback/

Finally under placement_specific field, `<AdgroupPlacementSpecificReviewFeedback>` object results in json not being able to be serialized. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup-placement-specific-review-feedback/

A sample of the value I'm trying the parse is as follows:

Note:

`<AdgroupPlacementSpecificReviewFeedback>` is what throws off the attempt to serialize the whole value as json.

```
{

'global': {
        'Personal attributes': 
            "Ads must not contain content that asserts or implies personal attributes. This includes direct or indirect assertions or implications about a person's race, ethnic origin, religion, beliefs, age, sexual orientation or practices, gender identity, disability, medical condition (including physical or mental health), financial status, voting status, membership in a trade union, criminal record or name. Read our Personal Attributes PolicyLearn more in our Business Help Centre"
    }, 

'placement_specific': <AdgroupPlacementSpecificReviewFeedback> {
        "facebook": {
            "Personal attributes": "Ads must not contain content that asserts or implies personal attributes. This includes direct or indirect assertions or implications about a person's race, ethnic origin, religion, beliefs, age, sexual orientation or practices, gender identity, disability, medical condition (including physical or mental health), financial status, voting status, membership in a trade union, criminal record or name. Read our Personal Attributes PolicyLearn more in our Business Help Centre"
        },

        "instagram": {
            "Personal attributes": "Ads must not contain content that asserts or implies personal attributes. This includes direct or indirect assertions or implications about a person's race, ethnic origin, religion, beliefs, age, sexual orientation or practices, gender identity, disability, medical condition (including physical or mental health), financial status, voting status, membership in a trade union, criminal record or name. Read our Personal Attributes PolicyLearn more in our Business Help Centre"
        }
    }
}
```

The current work around is to simply use regex to remove `<AdgroupPlacementSpecificReviewFeedback>` from the value. However, if there is any advice on how to correctly read this value as a json or dict then that would be really useful!

Comment: _"Unable to parse the following as json."_ - well, not surprising, because it isn't valid JSON. The quotes around the keys would need to be double instead of single ones, and `<AdgroupPlacementSpecificReviewFeedback>` would not have _any_ business being there in the first place.

Comment: Can you show how exactly you are getting this? I can't imagine that Facebook would pretend that this _was_ actually supposed to be JSON.

Comment: This is being pulled from facebook's marketing api, consider it as one of the values under a field. I'm not exactly aware what data type this is, and facebook's documentation (as linked above) also doesn't explicitly say how to read this with python. It can be read as json/dict without their ```<__facebookObject__>``` showing up in a value for one of the keys. 

If you have prior experience of correctly handling this without removing their object then that would be really helpful!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community I believe I've been quite specific, any suggestions how to improve will be appreciated!